# Go ODBC to an iSeries: SQL0104 - Message can not be translated successfully

Tags: go, odbc, ibm-midrange

I am attempting to use ODBC to query an IBM iSeries server (IBM i) using
https://code.google.com/p/odbc/.  I seem to think I had this working a while back when first testing but the
server has since been updated, iSeries Access updated, and I am using Go 1.3.1

It seems to connect fine, but the query causes an error.  I am guessing I am missing something with either the driver or the query being in the correct
encoding but I am not sure how to address it or if it is perhaps a bug with the odbc library and I should open an issue there.

My code is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    _ "code.google.com/p/odbc"
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("odbc", `
        Driver=iSeries Access ODBC Driver;
        System=myhost;
        Uid=myuserid;
        Pwd=mypassword`)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT 1 FROM sysibm.sysdummy1")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var number int
    for rows.Next() {
        rows.Scan(&number)
    }
    fmt.Println(number)
}
```

When running the above, I am getting the following error message:

```
SQLPrepare: {42000} [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Error message text unavailable.
Message can not be translated successfully.
```

Any ideas what is going wrong, what I can check, or how I can get this to work?

## Update

I did a test on a Linux VM and this works with that exact code.  I am able to use pyodbc with Python to connect on my Windows machine just fine using equivalent code, so this must be some sort of issue with this ODBC library on Windows.  I think at this point unless there are other ideas, I'm going to try some other libraries or open a bug report with the library author.

Comment: does the query work if you try to run it directly from the oracle console on the command line?

Comment: Yes, I connect regularly with other things such as Python/Excel, etc.

Comment: I never wrote anything in Go, but i think probably apostrophe (') should be replaced with Quotation mark (") after statement **sql.Open("odbc",**  and **Pwd=mypassword**

Comment: That is how you do multi-line strings in go, so it should be fine.  The connect actually works as I can see from server side, it is the query that fails.

Comment: `SQL0104` is "Token &1 was not valid. Valid tokens: &2." Not sure how that's helpful.

Comment: That code is normally a parse error as far as I know... which is why it mentions invalid tokens.  In this case that is not the text message which is why I think it must be something with encoding.

Comment: Yep, a parse error. Of course, without access to the fully-resolved text, it's hard to guess where in the statement any issue might be. And encoding seems as good a place to start as anywhere.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried this code with the latest driver version and golang 1.14 and it worked fine on both Windows 10 and Fedora 32.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark - what is the system CCSID set to?  DSPSYSVAL QCCSID.  If it is 65535, that means the system language is 'binary - do not translate'.  You might need to set the CCSID in your connection string if that's the case.

Comment: I just tried a couple CCSID options on connection string and it did not resolve it.  I also just deleted the *SQLPKG so it would rebuild it just to see if it was something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on Ubuntu 18 and Centos 8 (using .net though). It worked on Centos 7. Couldn't find any workaround tweaking odbc configs or connection strings. But after upgrading driver to 1.1.0.13 that issue was fixed.

Comment: There is a bug when using some versions of unixODBC when using the wide APIs (.NET tends to do this, since its strings are UTF-16) and a driver which does not provide the wide APIs. In this case, unixODBC will convert the SQLWCHAR string to an SQLCHAR string and pass it to the driver, but in doing so it accidentally includes the NUL terminator in the length. In the latest version of the driver, we detect this condition and ignore the extra NUL byte.